# Google analytics does not always update views

Tags: javascript, laravel, caching, google-analytics

We are using google analytics on Laravel project. The JS snippet

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics --> <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"></script>

<script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} 
gtag('js', new Date()); 
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X'); 
</script>
```

is inserted right after the **head** tag on each page following the recommendations fro Google.

The analytics, however, not always shows if there is a view (the JS is present on all pages).
On the hard refresh of the browser (Chrome in this case), the page views do appear in analytics.

Also, we notice that in Chrome's console Network tab for the record

https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X

corresponding to google analytics we see the following in the response

> Status Code: 200 (from memory cache)

and sometimes we get **disk cache** instead of **memory cache**.

It seems we are following the guidelines concerning google analytics, but the information doesn't appear in the analytics records.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: If that is your real GA tag in the source I strongly suggest you delete this question and ask it again

Comment: If you have just created the view try to wait some time (from a few minutes to a few hours). The data may appear after some time.